# How to return data from array where data includes any value , example 0?

Tags: javascript

I need the iteration to return objects from the array that contain some values.
I used the functions includes and some, and containts but they return true false values. I need whole objects

```
  filterDropdown(mealTypeNumber: number) {
    switch (mealTypeNumber) {
      case 0:
        // this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.filter(meal => meal.mealTypes == 0)  // this is worked when was be single values. Now is array of values
        this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.map(obj => console.log(obj.mealTypes.containts(0)))
        console.log('filtered meals' , this.meals) this is return me undefined undefined ....
        break;

      case 1:
        this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.filter(meal => meal.mealTypes == 1) 
        break;

      case 2:
        this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.filter(meal => meal.mealTypes == 2) 
        break;

      case 3:
        this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.filter(meal => meal.mealTypes == 3) 
        break;

      case 4:
        this.getMeals();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    } 
  }
```

Observe only the cases in case 0.
It should return to me all the values ​​from the array that contain 0.

allMealsFiltered is array like:

```
[
   {
      "name":"Testenine ",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":2,
      "preparationTime":0,
      "ingredients":[
         
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "kuhati na 200c "
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.lacanl.com/images/46e3ad266ee845b7b8273a1703dca936.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         0,
         1,
         2
      ],
      "id":191
   },
   {
      "name":"Belo meso",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":4,
      "preparationTime":0,
      "ingredients":[
         "belo meso",
         "jajca",
         "krompir"
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "u rerni"
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.lacanl.com/images/d157db3af3b5426cba30037cf99e27da.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         0,
         1,
         2,
         3
      ],
      "id":192
   },
   {
      "name":"Riba",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":4,
      "preparationTime":0,
      "ingredients":[
         "pastrmka",
         "limun"
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "ocisti dobro"
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.lacanl.com/images/23f9c73ee8f6402c806017abfe8d9fad.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         0,
         2
      ],
      "id":193
   },
   {
      "name":"Pasulj",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":3,
      "preparationTime":0,
      "ingredients":[
         "pasulja"
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "kruha"
      ],
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         1
      ],
      "id":194
   },
   {
      "name":"Ovsena kasa",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":2,
      "preparationTime":0,
      "ingredients":[
         
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "kasa"
      ],
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         0
      ],
      "id":195
   },
   {
      "name":"Juha",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":5,
      "preparationTime":0,
      "ingredients":[
         
      ],
      "instructions":[
         
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.lacanl.com/images/11ff16cf3fce44499aa79e348d62ed9d.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         2
      ],
      "id":196
   },
   {
      "name":"Kikiriki",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":5,
      "preparationTime":1980,
      "ingredients":[
         
      ],
      "instructions":[
         "ne slani"
      ],
      "pictureUrl":"https://www.lacanl.com/images/fc2771989d644cf0a4ae4d2d579487a9.jpg",
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         3
      ],
      "id":197
   },
   {
      "name":"Rolovana jajca",
      "description":"",
      "difficulty":5,
      "preparationTime":1860,
      "ingredients":[
         
      ],
      "instructions":[
         
      ],
      "recepieType":"",
      "mealTypes":[
         3
      ],
      "id":198
   }
]
```

**IN json only important values is mealTypes**

Comment: It seems you accidentally deleted a lot of relevant information. Please convince me of the reason for that edit. Ohterwise I will undo the accident.

Answer (score 4):

So you need to use `includes()` to which returns a boolean if the value is in the array.

```
filterDropdown(mealTypeNumber: number) {
    switch (mealTypeNumber) {
      case 0:
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.filter(meal => meal.mealTypes.includes(mealTypeNumber)) 
        break;
      case 4:
        this.getMeals();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `includes`, like so:

```
this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.filter(meal => meal.mealTypes.includes(0));
```

Also, you don't need to use a `switch` for that because you can simply use `mealTypeNumber` as the parameter to `includes`, like so:

```
filterDropdown(mealTypeNumber: number) {
  if(0 <= mealTypeNumber && mealTypeNumber <= 3) {
    this.meals = this.allMealsFiltered.filter(meal =>
      meal.mealTypes.includes(mealTypeNumber)
    );
  } else if(mealTypeNumber === 4) {
    this.getMeals();
  }
}
```